# Extension can't load NSLocalizedString (swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have an NSError extension and I run inside a new function  `NSLocalizedString("thisString", comment: "")`
but I get "thisString" and not the real string in `Localizable.strings`.

All the app is loading strings from there.

What can I do?